# Wrong date/time in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have problem adding the correct date/time to MySQL database.

My MySQL query is:

```
mysql_query("INSERT players SET time=NOW()") or die(mysql_error());
```

The correct time is ( 2015-08-14 19:27:05) using:

```
echo date("D M d, Y G:i a");
```

But the input in DB is : ( 2015-08-14 13:28:04 ) - using the DATETIME field.

I already added the following code, but it is not working:

```
<?php
     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
?>
```

I cannot understand why my PHP is echoing the correct time, but when adding it to the database it changes the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set the timezone in your database correctly?

Comment: [mySQL timezone may be different than your expecting](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/how-to-change-mysql-server-time-zone)

Comment: It is possible the php is run on a separate server from the database, and the servers are set to different times.

Comment: php and mysql can have different concepts of time even on same server

Comment: i dont have root access to the server, how can i set the timezone ? (i am using 000webhost.com )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working using :

```
mysql_query("INSERT players SET time='" . date("D M d, Y G:i a") . "'"  or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Good to run these two after making your connection:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Copenhagen' );
mysqli_query( $mysqli, "SET time_zone='" . date( 'P' ) . "'" );
```